# Increase the collectionView height constraint dynamically for the horizontal scrolling collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have added horizontal scrolling collection View in a scrollView and set the height as 10. I tried to change the height of the collection view dynamically using the above code it worked but cells are adding in multiple lines I mean just like  grid view but I need horizontal scrolling and should not view like grid view instead it should view as the number of items in a single row just like below image[image]

```
         self.hei_col_offers.constant = self.col_offers.contentSize.height
         self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Use composition layout https://github.com/nemecek-filip/CompositionalDiffablePlayground.ios
https://github.com/Lickability/collection-view-compositional-layout-demo

Comment: This line: `self.hei_col_offers.constant = self.col_offers.contentSize.height` doesn't make any sense. It's telling the collection view to be tall enough to show all of its content. You (probably) want to set the height constant to the height of a single cell.